# In which file add line to set pages of will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I understand that `WillPaginate.per_page = 10` set the size of pages globally, my question is: in which file do I have to set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper place to set this is inside `config/application.rb` or if you wish to have different `per_page` values per environment, use the default on `config/application.rb`, then override in eg. `config/production.rb` etc.